# Why the upvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

I realize I may be a bit less forgiving than others. However, I'd like to ask **why** some questions are getting so many up votes?

Questions which are *litterally*....

> How do I do this in [ApplicationX]?
> [image]

There's no effort shown **whatsoever**. Not even a cursory explanation of how a user *thinks* they may be able to accomplish this. It's purely a *"please provide a tutorial for this image"* question. Yet they **always** seem to get at least one, if not multiple, up votes.

Am I missing some reason these questions are deserving of up votes?

I'm not suggesting all of these are worthy of *down* votes, but they *certainly* are *not* deserving of up votes. If every poor, low effort question gets up votes, why bother with voting at all?

- [How to make this strange embossed apple logo?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/152293/how-to-make-this-strange-embossed-apple-logo)
- [Hello. How can I make this effect in illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/152236/hello-how-can-i-make-this-effect-in-illustrator)
- [How to stack animated gifs?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/152314/how-to-stack-animated-gifs)
- [How to get this rough grain effect on photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/152297/how-to-get-this-rough-grain-effect-on-photoshop)

Comment: FWIW two of these hit HNQ at some point

Comment: HNQ may be the issue then `:)` Shame these are selected for that all it does is promote the behavior.

Comment: I've also noticed this pattern. There are several other examples lately. It's also a problem when answers just becomes recipes to follow and don't seek to explain the mechanisms behind. (I'm not saying I haven't provided answers like that myself from time to time.)

Comment: @curious uh, what is HNQ ?

Comment: Hot Network Questions @Programmer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some reasons why people voted up such questions:

- They wanted to ask *the same (or similar) question,* and now they don't need to think how to formulate it, because they found it done, so they are genuinely thankful that someone do the work for them.
- They accidentally found

  - the *nice* answer, or
  - the answer to *their own problem,* or
  - the interesting feature or workflow, *about which they didn't know previously,* and which may be useful for them in the future,

  so they are thankful not only to the answerer, but also to the OP of the question for giving an opportunity for such a useful answer.

Comment: +1 fair points I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 9):

Not all voters are necessarily big GD users.
A person mostly hanging on stackexhange or a person who just wants to know the answer, might look at this differently.

Of the questions the apple effect one is somewhat genuinely interesting. Although i haven voted because it does not show any effort. Note this post is on the hot list so expect it to have a lot of up votes.

In the end they are voting the way they want this site to be used, while you are voting the way you want. Our core user base is now just so low that our own voice is being overshadowed by those who want us to be graphix help channel. See ultimately there are 2 kinds of users those that seek answers and those that answer. They also have different voting patterns.

So I would say we should try to vote worthy questions more so that 2 votes seems like a rotten deal.

Answer (score 5):

This complaint is a recurring issue: you are hardly the first to dislike tutorial-on-demand answers, nor the first to post about them.

Case in point:

- [What to do with tutorial requests? -- part II](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/what-to-do-with-tutorial-requests-part-ii)
- [Changing how we handle low-effort and tutorial-on-demand questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/changing-how-we-handle-low-effort-and-tutorial-on-demand-questions)
- [Why do how-to requests bother you?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3378/why-do-how-to-requests-bother-you)
- [Why is everything suddenly "too broad"?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/why-is-everything-suddenly-too-broad)

The outcomes of these Meta posts, especially the first one, is that low-effort, tut-on-demand questions are apparently a desirable aspect of this community.

No, I don't agree either. Yes, I hate them too. You can choose to get annoyed over them or shrug and move on. I chose the latter.

Comment: Well, like i said the crowd is bimodal. So for those who would want to ask a question. This is the easiest route. So if you want them to ask a great questiin they should probably need a springboard question.

Comment: In this case, I feel my questions which were downvoted were actually better than these ;) Because at least they were graphic design questions.

Answer (score 0):

What I feel: Sometimes I've seen design questions which has done effort and are less like 'how to do this in photoshop' don't get any support, whereas a very basic question about 'how to do this in photoshop' gets 3-4-5 upvotes.

I'm not talking about my own questions. I've just observed it in past. I can't provide links as I don't remember now.

One reason is I guess users are offline on some days and question gets less views. While some other similar question gets 'lucky' get gets the support.

Support is fine, but in the end we see the difference and wonder why it happened.

Also, someone experienced on a different SE once told me that SE is run by community, not by a single user. So it's not really in our hand. It depends on how community takes it.